Convert safetensors model format(LLaVA model) into gguf format
I want to do LLaVA inference in ollama, so I need to convert it in gguf file format.
My model has the file format safetensors.(trained with lora)
It seems that ollama supports only llama, but not llava as shown here,
https://github.com/ollama/ollama/blob/main/docs/import.md
I followed the instruction of llama.cpp, and used the code convert_lora_to_gguf.py here,
https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp/blob/master/convert_lora_to_gguf.py
But I get an error like,
ERROR:lora-to-gguf:Model LlavaLlamaForCausalLM is not supported

If I write llama model in config.json of model file and run following code, then I got another error.
model_instance.gguf_writer.add_string(gguf.Keys.General.TYPE, gguf.GGUFType.ADAPTER)
model_instance.gguf_writer.add_string(gguf.Keys.Adapter.TYPE, "lora")
model_instance.gguf_writer.add_float32(gguf.Keys.Adapter.LORA_ALPHA, float(alpha))
model_instance.gguf_writer.add_quantization_version(gguf.GGML_QUANT_VERSION)
logger.info("Exporting model...")
model_instance.write()
logger.info(f"Model successfully exported to {model_instance.fname_out}")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jjjy2\OneDrive\Desktop\VLM_FastAPI\ollama\convert_lora_to_gguf.py", line 373, in <module>
    model_instance.gguf_writer.add_string(gguf.Keys.General.FILE_TYPE, gguf.GGUFType.ADAPTER)
AttributeError: module 'gguf' has no attribute 'GGUFType'

It seems that all codes and gguf package don't support llava, but llama only. I have to convert my own trained model into gguf. I cannot use gguf llava model from hugging face for inference.
Is there a way to convert it?

https://medium.com/@manish.thota1999/an-experiment-to-unlock-ollamas-potential-video-question-answering-e2b4d1bfb5ba
python3 /home/myles/llama.cpp/examples/llava/llava_surgery_v2.py -C -m /home/myles/llama.cpp/checkpoint-300



import argparse
import os
import json
import re

import torch
import numpy as np
from gguf import *

from transformers import SiglipModel, SiglipProcessor, SiglipVisionModel


TEXT = "clip.text"
VISION = "clip.vision"


def k(raw_key: str, arch: str) -> str:
    return raw_key.format(arch=arch)


def should_skip_tensor(name: str, has_text: bool, has_vision: bool, has_llava: bool) -> bool:
    if name in (
        "logit_scale",
        "text_model.embeddings.position_ids",
        "vision_model.embeddings.position_ids",
    ):
        return True

    if has_llava and name in ["visual_projection.weight", "vision_model.post_layernorm.weight", "vision_model.post_layernorm.bias"]:
        return True

    if name.startswith("v") and not has_vision:
        return True

    if name.startswith("t") and not has_text:
        return True

    return False


def get_tensor_name(name: str) -> str:
    if "projection" in name:
        return name
    if "mm_projector" in name:
        name = name.replace("model.mm_projector", "mm")
        name = re.sub(r'mm\.mlp\.mlp', 'mm.model.mlp', name, count=1)
        name = re.sub(r'mm\.peg\.peg', 'mm.model.peg', name, count=1)
        return name

    return name.replace("text_model", "t").replace("vision_model", "v").replace("encoder.layers", "blk").replace("embeddings.", "").replace("_proj", "").replace("self_attn.", "attn_").replace("layer_norm", "ln").replace("layernorm", "ln").replace("mlp.fc1", "ffn_down").replace("mlp.fc2", "ffn_up").replace("embedding", "embd").replace("final", "post").replace("layrnorm", "ln")


def bytes_to_unicode():
    """
    Returns list of utf-8 byte and a corresponding list of unicode strings.
    The reversible bpe codes work on unicode strings.
    This means you need a large # of unicode characters in your vocab if you want to avoid UNKs.
    When you're at something like a 10B token dataset you end up needing around 5K for decent coverage.
    This is a significant percentage of your normal, say, 32K bpe vocab.
    To avoid that, we want lookup tables between utf-8 bytes and unicode strings.
    And avoids mapping to whitespace/control characters the bpe code barfs on.
    """
    bs = (
        list(range(ord("!"), ord("~") + 1))
        + list(range(ord("¡"), ord("¬") + 1))
        + list(range(ord("®"), ord("ÿ") + 1))
    )
    cs = bs[:]
    n = 0
    for b in range(2**8):
        if b not in bs:
            bs.append(b)
            cs.append(2**8 + n)
            n += 1
    cs = [chr(n) for n in cs]
    return dict(zip(bs, cs))


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model-dir", help="Path to model directory cloned from HF Hub", required=True)
ap.add_argument("--use-f32", action="store_true", default=False, help="Use f32 instead of f16")
ap.add_argument("--text-only", action="store_true", required=False,
                help="Save a text-only model. It can't be used to encode images")
ap.add_argument("--vision-only", action="store_true", required=False,
                help="Save a vision-only model. It can't be used to encode texts")
ap.add_argument("--clip-model-is-vision", action="store_true", required=False,
                help="The clip model is a pure vision model (ShareGPT4V vision extract for example)")
ap.add_argument("--clip-model-is-openclip", action="store_true", required=False,
                help="The clip model is from openclip (for ViT-SO400M type))")
ap.add_argument("--llava-projector", help="Path to llava.projector file. If specified, save an image encoder for LLaVA models.")
ap.add_argument("--projector-type", help="Type of projector. Possible values: mlp, ldp, ldpv2", choices=["mlp", "ldp", "ldpv2"], default="mlp")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output-dir", help="Directory to save GGUF files. Default is the original model directory", default=None)
# Example --image_mean 0.48145466 0.4578275 0.40821073 --image_std 0.26862954 0.26130258 0.27577711
# Example --image_mean 0.5 0.5 0.5 --image_std 0.5 0.5 0.5
default_image_mean = [0.48145466, 0.4578275, 0.40821073]
default_image_std = [0.26862954, 0.26130258, 0.27577711]
ap.add_argument('--image-mean', type=float, nargs='+', help='Mean of the images for normalization (overrides processor) ', default=None)
ap.add_argument('--image-std', type=float, nargs='+', help='Standard deviation of the images for normalization (overrides processor)', default=None)

# with proper
args = ap.parse_args()


if args.text_only and args.vision_only:
    print("--text-only and --image-only arguments cannot be specified at the same time.")
    exit(1)

if args.use_f32:
    print("WARNING: Weights for the convolution op is always saved in f16, as the convolution op in GGML does not support 32-bit kernel weights yet.")

# output in the same directory as the model if output_dir is None
dir_model = args.model_dir

if args.clip_model_is_vision or not os.path.exists(dir_model + "/vocab.json") or args.clip_model_is_openclip:
    vocab = None
    tokens = None
else:
    with open(dir_model + "/vocab.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        vocab = json.load(f)
        tokens = [key for key in vocab]

with open(dir_model + "/config.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    config = json.load(f)
    if args.clip_model_is_vision:
        v_hparams = config
        t_hparams = None
    else:
        v_hparams = config["vision_config"]
        t_hparams = config["text_config"]

# possible data types
#   ftype == 0 -> float32
#   ftype == 1 -> float16
#
# map from ftype to string
ftype_str = ["f32", "f16"]

ftype = 1
if args.use_f32:
    ftype = 0

if args.clip_model_is_vision or args.clip_model_is_openclip:
    model = SiglipVisionModel.from_pretrained(dir_model)
    processor = None
else:
    model = SiglipModel.from_pretrained(dir_model)
    processor = SiglipProcessor.from_pretrained(dir_model)

fname_middle = None
has_text_encoder = True
has_vision_encoder = True
has_llava_projector = False
if args.text_only:
    fname_middle = "text-"
    has_vision_encoder = False
elif args.llava_projector is not None:
    fname_middle = "mmproj-"
    has_text_encoder = False
    has_llava_projector = True
elif args.vision_only:
    fname_middle = "vision-"
    has_text_encoder = False
else:
    fname_middle = ""

output_dir = args.output_dir if args.output_dir is not None else dir_model
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
output_prefix = os.path.basename(output_dir).replace("ggml_", "")
fname_out = os.path.join(output_dir, f"{fname_middle}model-{ftype_str[ftype]}.gguf")
fout = GGUFWriter(path=fname_out, arch="clip")

fout.add_bool("clip.has_text_encoder", has_text_encoder)
fout.add_bool("clip.has_vision_encoder", has_vision_encoder)
fout.add_bool("clip.has_llava_projector", has_llava_projector)
fout.add_file_type(ftype)
model_name = config["_name_or_path"] if "_name_or_path" in config else os.path.basename(dir_model)
fout.add_name(model_name)
if args.text_only:
    fout.add_description("text-only CLIP model")
elif args.vision_only and not has_llava_projector:
    fout.add_description("vision-only CLIP model")
elif has_llava_projector:
    fout.add_description("image encoder for LLaVA")
    # add projector type
    fout.add_string("clip.projector_type", args.projector_type)
else:
    fout.add_description("two-tower CLIP model")

if has_text_encoder:
    assert t_hparams is not None
    assert tokens is not None
    # text_model hparams
    fout.add_uint32(k(KEY_CONTEXT_LENGTH, TEXT), t_hparams["max_position_embeddings"])
    fout.add_uint32(k(KEY_EMBEDDING_LENGTH, TEXT), t_hparams["hidden_size"])
    fout.add_uint32(k(KEY_FEED_FORWARD_LENGTH, TEXT), t_hparams["intermediate_size"])
    fout.add_uint32("clip.text.projection_dim", t_hparams.get("projection_dim", config["projection_dim"]))
    fout.add_uint32(k(KEY_ATTENTION_HEAD_COUNT, TEXT), t_hparams["num_attention_heads"])
    fout.add_float32(k(KEY_ATTENTION_LAYERNORM_EPS, TEXT), t_hparams["layer_norm_eps"])
    fout.add_uint32(k(KEY_BLOCK_COUNT, TEXT), t_hparams["num_hidden_layers"])
    fout.add_token_list(tokens)

if has_vision_encoder:
    # vision_model hparams
    fout.add_uint32("clip.vision.image_size", v_hparams["image_size"])
    fout.add_uint32("clip.vision.patch_size", v_hparams["patch_size"])
    fout.add_uint32(k(KEY_EMBEDDING_LENGTH, VISION), v_hparams["hidden_size"])
    fout.add_uint32(k(KEY_FEED_FORWARD_LENGTH, VISION), v_hparams["intermediate_size"])
    fout.add_uint32("clip.vision.projection_dim", v_hparams.get("projection_dim", config["projection_dim"]))
    fout.add_uint32(k(KEY_ATTENTION_HEAD_COUNT, VISION), v_hparams["num_attention_heads"])
    fout.add_float32(k(KEY_ATTENTION_LAYERNORM_EPS, VISION), v_hparams["layer_norm_eps"])
    block_count = v_hparams["num_hidden_layers"] - 1 if has_llava_projector else v_hparams["num_hidden_layers"]
    fout.add_uint32(k(KEY_BLOCK_COUNT, VISION), block_count)
                            #     /**
                            #      "image_grid_pinpoints": [
                            #         [
                            #         336,
                            #         672
                            #         ],
                            #         [
                            #         672,
                            #         336
                            #         ],
                            #         [
                            #         672,
                            #         672
                            #         ],
                            #         [
                            #         1008,
                            #         336
                            #         ],
                            #         [
                            #         336,
                            #         1008
                            #         ]
                            #     ],
                            #     Flattened:
                            #     [
                            #         336, 672,
                            #         672, 336,
                            #         672, 672,
                            #         1008, 336,
                            #         336, 1008
                            #     ]
                            #  *
                            #  */
    if "image_grid_pinpoints" in v_hparams:
        # flatten it
        image_grid_pinpoints = []
        for pinpoint in v_hparams["image_grid_pinpoints"]:
            for p in pinpoint:
                image_grid_pinpoints.append(p)
        fout.add_array("clip.vision.image_grid_pinpoints", image_grid_pinpoints)
    if "image_crop_resolution" in v_hparams:
        fout.add_uint32("clip.vision.image_crop_resolution", v_hparams["image_crop_resolution"])
    if "image_aspect_ratio" in v_hparams:
        fout.add_string("clip.vision.image_aspect_ratio", v_hparams["image_aspect_ratio"])
    if "image_split_resolution" in v_hparams:
        fout.add_uint32("clip.vision.image_split_resolution", v_hparams["image_split_resolution"])
    if "mm_patch_merge_type" in v_hparams:
        fout.add_string("clip.vision.mm_patch_merge_type", v_hparams["mm_patch_merge_type"])
    if "mm_projector_type" in v_hparams:
        fout.add_string("clip.vision.mm_projector_type", v_hparams["mm_projector_type"])


    if processor is not None:
        image_mean = processor.image_processor.image_mean if args.image_mean is None or args.image_mean == default_image_mean else args.image_mean  # pyright: ignore[reportAttributeAccessIssue]
        image_std = processor.image_processor.image_std if args.image_std is None or args.image_std == default_image_std else args.image_std  # pyright: ignore[reportAttributeAccessIssue]
    else:
        image_mean = args.image_mean if args.image_mean is not None else default_image_mean
        image_std = args.image_std if args.image_std is not None else default_image_std
    fout.add_array("clip.vision.image_mean", image_mean)
    fout.add_array("clip.vision.image_std", image_std)

use_gelu = v_hparams["hidden_act"] == "gelu"
fout.add_bool("clip.use_gelu", use_gelu)


if has_llava_projector:
    model.vision_model.encoder.layers.pop(-1)  # pyright: ignore[reportAttributeAccessIssue]
    projector = torch.load(args.llava_projector)
    for name, data in projector.items():
        name = get_tensor_name(name)
        # pw and dw conv ndim==4
        if data.ndim == 2 or data.ndim == 4:
            data = data.squeeze().numpy().astype(np.float16)
        else:
            data = data.squeeze().numpy().astype(np.float32)

        fout.add_tensor(name, data)

    print("Projector tensors added\n")

state_dict = model.state_dict()  # pyright: ignore[reportAttributeAccessIssue]
for name, data in state_dict.items():
    if should_skip_tensor(name, has_text_encoder, has_vision_encoder, has_llava_projector):
        # we don't need this
        print(f"skipping parameter: {name}")
        continue

    name = get_tensor_name(name)
    data = data.squeeze().numpy()

    n_dims = len(data.shape)

    # ftype == 0 -> float32, ftype == 1 -> float16
    ftype_cur = 0
    if n_dims == 4:
        print(f"tensor {name} is always saved in f16")
        data = data.astype(np.float16)
        ftype_cur = 1
    elif ftype == 1:
        if name[-7:] == ".weight" and n_dims == 2:
            print("  Converting to float16")
            data = data.astype(np.float16)
            ftype_cur = 1
        else:
            print("  Converting to float32")
            data = data.astype(np.float32)
            ftype_cur = 0
    else:
        if data.dtype != np.float32:
            print("  Converting to float32")
            data = data.astype(np.float32)
            ftype_cur = 0

    print(f"{name} - {ftype_str[ftype_cur]} - shape = {data.shape}")
    fout.add_tensor(name, data)


fout.write_header_to_file()
fout.write_kv_data_to_file()
fout.write_tensors_to_file()
fout.close()

print("Done. Output file: " + fname_out)

 ./llama-llava-cli -m /home/myles/llama.cpp/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct/meta-llama-3.1-8B-instruction_f32.gguf --mmproj /home/myles/llama.cpp/vit/mmproj-model-f16.gguf  --image /home/myles/Desktop/extreme_ironing.jpg -c 4096 --n-gpu-layers 33 -p "how many cars are shown in the image" 

crate a config file json like so
{
  "_name_or_path": "google/siglip-so400m-patch14-384",
  "architectures": [
    "siglip_vision_model"
  ],
  "attention_dropout": 0.0,
  "dropout": 0.0,
  "hidden_act": "silu",
  "hidden_size": 1152,
  "image_size": 384,
  "initializer_factor": 1.0,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 4304,
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-06,
  "model_type": "siglip_vision_model",
  "num_attention_heads": 16,
  "num_channels": 3,
  "num_hidden_layers": 27,
  "patch_size": 14,
  "projection_dim": 768,
  "torch_dtype": "bfloat16",
  "transformers_version": "4.45.0.dev0",
  "image_aspect_ratio": "anyres_max_9",
  "image_grid_pinpoints": [
    [
      384,
      384
    ],
    [
      384,
      768
    ],
    [
      384,
      1152
    ],
    [
      384,
      1536
    ],
    [
      384,
      1920
    ],
    [
      384,
      2304
    ],
    [
      768,
      384
    ],
    [
      768,
      768
    ],
    [
      768,
      1152
    ],
    [
      768,
      1536
    ],
    [
      768,
      1920
    ],
    [
      768,
      2304
    ],
    [
      1152,
      384
    ],
    [
      1152,
      768
    ],
    [
      1152,
      1152
    ],
    [
      1152,
      1536
    ],
    [
      1152,
      1920
    ],
    [
      1152,
      2304
    ],
    [
      1536,
      384
    ],
    [
      1536,
      768
    ],
    [
      1536,
      1152
    ],
    [
      1536,
      1536
    ],
    [
      1536,
      1920
    ],
    [
      1536,
      2304
    ],
    [
      1920,
      384
    ],
    [
      1920,
      768
    ],
    [
      1920,
      1152
    ],
    [
      1920,
      1536
    ],
    [
      1920,
      1920
    ],
    [
      1920,
      2304
    ],
    [
      2304,
      384
    ],
    [
      2304,
      768
    ],
    [
      2304,
      1152
    ],
    [
      2304,
      1536
    ],
    [
      2304,
      1920
    ],
    [
      2304,
      2304
    ]
  ],
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "max_position_embeddings": 131072,
  "mlp_bias": false,
  "mm_hidden_size": 1152,
  "mm_newline_position": "grid",
  "mm_patch_merge_type": "spatial_unpad",
  "mm_projector_type": "mlp2x_gelu",
  "mm_spatial_pool_mode": "bilinear",
  "mm_tunable_parts": "mm_vision_tower,mm_mlp_adapter,mm_language_model",
  "mm_use_im_patch_token": false,
  "mm_use_im_start_end": false,
  "mm_vision_select_feature": "patch",
  "mm_vision_select_layer": -2,
  "mm_vision_tower": "google/siglip-so400m-patch14-384",
  "mm_vision_tower_lr": 2e-06
}

